# How to import product name with ™ and ® symbol?

Tags: magento2, product, import, magento-2.1, character-encoding

I have products where it is important to **have symbols like ™ and ®**, as these are necessary to be with product name. When I tried to import such products, it says "**General system exception happened**" on "**Check Data**".

After removing same symbols, file is being validated successfully.

I am using Magento 2.1.0.

Comment: I have same issue let me know if you got solution.

Comment: You can use the link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pretty sure it's caused by the fact that those characters are not supported when copied/pasted like this.

I reckon you should use their HTML equivalent instead:

- ™ : `&trade;`
- ® : `&reg;`

The W3C provides a nice character entity reference if you need to find out more characters: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: The collation of the table should allow UTF-8, though. Perhaps the encoding of the source document is screwed up?

Comment: @philwinkle it really depends on what you copy/paste. I faced the issue a few times specially copying stuff from MS Word. Always found it safer to go the HTML code way

Comment: After adding `&trade;` for `TM`, in mini-cart still it shows string `&trade;` instead. Can you help me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML encoded characters as suggested by previous answers works for fields that allow HTML and are always used in HTML context.

This is true for product descriptions and other WYSIWYG fields, but **not** for product names. In invoice PDFs for example you will see the plain text `&trade;` instead of the trade symbol if the name was imported with `&trade;`.

Instead, make sure that your input file is correctly encoded in UTF-8. Any decent text editor (such as notepad++) can detect and **convert character encoding**. Make sure to use **UTF-8 without BOM**.

Answer (score 0):

For these special characters, we need to encode to its HTML. There is a sites - [HTML Entities Encoder / Decoder](http://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder) can help us to encode and decode a piece of text to its HTML equivalent. We also make a reference [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).